# How would I stop my shape from moving using keypressed?

Tags: javascript, java, processing

How would I make my shape stop every time I press the spacebar and move when I press the spacebar again.

Answer (score 2):

To pause and resume updating the position you would need to create a separate variable to keep track of this state change: a boolean value is perfect in this case.

e.g.

```
boolean shouldSquareUpdate = true;
```

You can use [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) to listen for key changes in Processing:

```
void draw(){
}
void keyPressed(){
  println("key: " + key + " keyCode: " + keyCode);
}
```

The next part is toggling the boolean value:

- if the value was `true`, set it to `false`
- if it was `false`, set it to `true`

e.g.

```
void keyPressed(){
  // toggle boolean (if true, set it to false, if false, set it to true)
  if(shouldSquareUpdate == true){
    shouldSquareUpdate = false;
  }else{
    shouldSquareUpdate = true;
  }
}
```

This can be more elegantly be solved with the [logical NOT operator](https://processing.org/reference/logicalNOT.html), which essentially flips the state of the boolean:

```
void keyPressed(){
  // toggle boolean (if true, set it to false, if false, set it to true)
  shouldSquareUpdate = !shouldSquareUpdate;
}
```

Finally, you would use this condition to determine if the `y` value should be updated (or not):

```
// update only if value is true
  if(shouldSquareUpdate){
    y += dy;
  }
```

The full sketch would like so:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

int dy = 1;

boolean shouldSquareUpdate = true;

void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  surface.setResizable(true);
}

void draw() {
  background(240, 240, 240);
  fill(255, 147, 79);
  rect(x, y, 90, 90);
  // update only if value is true
  if(shouldSquareUpdate){
    y += dy;
  }
  if(y + 90 > height || y < 0) {
    dy *= -1;
  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  // toggle boolean (if true, set it to false, if false, set it to true)
  shouldSquareUpdate = !shouldSquareUpdate;
}
```

Regarding

> how would I make my square move in 8 equal steps?

That should be a matter of simply updating the `dy` value which you currently set a 1 (pixel per frame) to be an 8th of the total travel distance (height):

e.g.

```
// in setup()
dy = height / 8;
```

Bare in mind that 720 / 8 = 90 pixels per frame, with 60 frames a second that would be 5400 pixels per second: waaay to fast for the motion be legible.

You can use the same principle to maybe move the box in 32 equal steps ? 
e.g.

```
void setup() {
  size(1280, 720);
  surface.setResizable(true);
  // make square move in 32 equal steps: increment 32th of the total height
  dy = height / 32;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, you made it a lot clearer than my lecturer, but how would you integrate the space bar so it will only stop and start when I press it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're very capable of doing that using the `keyPressed()` function (as you can see above) and checking if the `key` that is pressed is the space character(`' '`) (or alternatively use `keyCode` if that's easier with the `println("key: " + key + " keyCode: " + keyCode);` example and write the `if` condition for the right keyCode value). Good luck and have fun tweaking/breaking/fixing code :)